# what is the maximum number of parameters a PL/SQL procedure can have?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to develop a PL/SQL procedure that needs at least 26 parameters to be passed in it. what is the maximum number of parameters a PL/SQL procedure can have? And what are the consequences of having a large number of parameters? will it cause any inconvenience?

Comment: How hard is it to try it out?

Comment: Or read the fine manual ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name quite hard as i have to give a lot of effort to develop the other parts of that  particular procedure... otherwise i wouldn't have posted it here.

Comment: No it's not "quite hard", because you can create a simple procedure that does nothing with 26 parameters. There is no need to "*develop the other parts*" just to confirm that you can pass 26 parameters.

Comment: With a simple search in google, this is the first result. It is easier than reading the manual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading the fine manual: [PL/SQL Program Limits](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/limits.htm)

> number of formal parameters in an explicit cursor, function, or procedure: 65536

You'll run into other problems before hitting this limit.

Comment: :-)  and if it's not enough, use records as parameter. I guess you can also have 65536 records and each of them can have another 65535 columns ...

Comment: @PT_STAR That's very true. Please however note there is a rather low limit for _"levels of record nesting: 32"_. ;)