# How many IN, OUT and IN OUT parameters can be used in pl sql function and procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to know how many IN, OUT and IN OUT parameters can be used in a function and how many in a procedure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the maximum number of parameters a PL/SQL procedure can have?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534348/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-parameters-a-pl-sql-procedure-can-have)

Comment: If you have more than about 10 parameters, you may want to consider using record types with logical groupings, so that future programmers don't get lost :)

Answer (score 2):

From [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/limits.htm):

> number of formal parameters in an explicit cursor, function, or
>   procedure 65536